# Windows 7 Tablet Touchscreen Sensitivity, Can it be adjusted?

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen, tablet-pc

currently I have a Windows 7 Touchscreen tablet.  The tablet is ok otherwise, but the screen is *very sensitive* to the point where I barely graze with a finger or its pen and it registers as a touch.  Is there any way I can adjust to a more comfortable sensitivity level in Windows 7 Tablet?

Comment: Have you tried coating the screen in a thin layer of glue from a glue stick, or perhaps olive oil?

Comment: wha....proof needed on glue being good on touch screens....olive oil would be temporary.